# Custom Category Attribute not in Repository

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, flat, repositories

I created a custom category multiselect attribute. (it's even a custom source but that does not matter).

Everything is OK on save, admin forms OK, even the flat contains my values. ( thx to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/417 )

**BUT, when i do a list/get on front through repository, my category object does not have the values...** (flat is activated)

I found an event in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Flat`

```
// Allow extensions to modify select (e.g. add custom category attributes to select)
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before', ['select' => $select]);
```

- Is that the only way ?  It seems weird to me when i think about the XML of Magento 1.
- Do i have to modify anything else ?

edit: Even with flat disabled, i can't get it...

edit2: ok, i'm stupid. A part of the problem was because i was in `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category` function `canShow` , and it uses a "hard coded" collection through the `getCategoryTree` function . Hooray, another plugin to write. The funny thing is that i know have a *string* instead of an *array* through get. As if the afterLoad was not called... Another mystery...

But then... the observer i gave. What is its purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a search for the event name revealed that it isn't actually used anywhere in the system. So, the best guess I have is what I can ascertain from the comment: the core team wants to expose a way to add custom attributes to the select.